# Close popups in Oddschecker using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Need to close the cookies and ad popup on this page, I know you can do it using webdriverwait and either CSS_SELECTOR or X tags but I can't find the specific tags for the buttons, as when you click 'inspect' they disappear.

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s=Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(https://www.oddschecker.com/)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element <kbd>OK</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.oddschecker.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='CookieBannerAcceptButton']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.oddschecker.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='OK']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```